# Composer returns nothing to update while trying to update sentry-laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6, sentry

I'm trying to update the sentry-laravel package because we are using version 0.10.0 while the version 1.4.1 it is available.

I've searched about the composer update command and found that you should only use **composer update vendor/package** or **composer update vendor/package --with-dependencies** so I did it and in the end I received the message: Nothing to update.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong but I don't think so...

We're using Laravel 5.6 and I am using Composer 1.9.0

The composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.55",
        "bacon/bacon-qr-code": "1.0.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/homestead": "^7.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "plivo/php-sdk": "^4.0",
        "pragmarx/google2fa-laravel": "^0.2.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.10.0",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~2",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.12"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-query-detector": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "imanghafoori/laravel-anypass": "^1.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
```

Anyone have been through this sometime?

Comment: can you share your composer.json file?

Comment: @PavelLint post edited, composer.json require section is there now. thanks!

Comment: looks like you can update to 0.11.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update to the latest version because it's incompatible with Laravel 5.6

From the [package's readme](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel#laravel-version-compatibility)

### Laravel Version Compatibility

- Laravel `4.2.x` is supported until version `0.8.x`
- Laravel `<= 5.7.x` on PHP `<= 7.0` is supported until version `0.11.x`
- Laravel `>= 5.x.x` on PHP `>= 7.1` is supported in the most recent version
- Laravel `>= 6.x.x` on PHP `>= 7.2` is supported in the most recent version

So you have to update Laravel as well if you want to update the package

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh! Now I see... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't update to the latest version, but you can update to 0.11.x if you change your composer.json entry to

```
"sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.11.*"
```